# How to change behavior of <a href="somewhere.html" id="link"> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, href

For those with javascript enabled,click on them should do **OnClick**()

For those with javascript disabled,click on them should just go to somewhere.html,

Suppose only $('#link') is accessible,how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('#link').click(function() { 
    //...
    return false;
});
```

By writing `return false`, the link will not be followed.

If Javascript is disabled, the click handler won't be added, and the link will behave normally.

Comment: What about if i want  to behave normally depending on a condition?

Comment: @Darwin: Use an `if` statement?

Comment: what I mean is. what do I need to return on the function for the link would be followed?

Comment: @Darwin: `true`, or nothing.

Answer (score 2):

$("#link").bind("click", function(e){alert("clicked"); e.preventDefault(); return false;});

This will alert "clicked" and then cancel the default action. If Javascript is disabled, the link is followed.

Comment: What's the difference between $.bind and $.click ?

Comment: $.bind also takes the name of the event to bind to: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind#typedatafn  This answer is wrong and will not work because it doesn't pass the event name.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, forgot to add the "click" argument. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`click`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click) function. Add `return false` to the end of your function to prevent the default action of the click, which is following the hyperlink:

```
$("#link").click(function() { onClick(); return false; });
```

Comment: Now there is - `return false`.